# Configurating the postfix on mavericks mac os doesnt work

Tags: macos, configuration, sendmail, osx-mavericks, postfix-mta

In the last month I tried to get my Mac to send e-mails. I did everything but at the end when I send the email through the terminal I don't receive it in my Gmail account. Also tried it with gmx but no luck either. Please any tips

Output of `postconf -n`

```
biff = no 
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix 
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5 
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1 
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
imap_submit_cred_file = –
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = _postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 10485760
mydomain_fallback = localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, [::1]/128 
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /private/var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = [smtp.gmx.com]:25
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/examples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = _postdrop
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = 
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1 
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt 
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated permit 
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium 
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = SSLv2, aNULL, ADH, eNULL 
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom 
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Comment: What steps did you do? You write that you did everything but how one can guess what you did?

Comment: can you post the output of `postconf -n` and the log lines generated by postfix to help you better.

Comment: biff = no
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
imap_submit_cred_file =

Comment: inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = _postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 10485760
mydomain_fallback = localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, [::1]/128
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /private/var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
recipient_delimiter = +

Comment: relayhost = [smtp.gmx.com]:25
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/examples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = _postdrop
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated permit
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = SSLv2, aNULL, ADH, eNULL
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550

Comment: @user3670165 I've got a gist for the process I follow on Mavericks: https://gist.github.com/larrybotha/6009971